# If I instantiate a LinearLayout as a copy of an existing one, once I perform a chance on the original, it's also done on the copy

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout

I've a LinearLayout with several views on it. So what I want to achieve, is to duplicate this LinearLayout and use it somewhen. But when I perform changes on the original LinearLayout, like method `removeAllViews()`, it's also done on the copy.

Example:

```
Log.d("debug1","1 vc"+variableContent.getChildCount());
this.anticsModulsVisibles = variableContent; //copy of the linearLayout
Log.d("debug1","2 vc"+variableContent.getChildCount());
Log.d("debug1","2.1 amv"+anticsModulsVisibles.getChildCount());
variableContent.removeAllViews(); //i remove the content of the original
Log.d("debug1","3 vc"+variableContent.getChildCount());
Log.d("debug1","4 amv"+anticsModulsVisibles.getChildCount());
```

And the output of log:

> 1 vc2
>
> 2 vc2
>
> 2.1 amv2
>
> 3 vc0
>
> 4 amv0

As you can see, the `anticsModulsVisibles` or `amv` is following what is happening to the original.

Can I avoid this? Maybe setting it as a "final"? Is it possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any time you see changes to one object reflecting in what you think is a copy, 100% of the time the problem is that you don't have a copy but rather a second reference to the original object.  You will need to do some digging into `LinearLayout` to determine whether the `.clone()` method is fully implemented, or manually make a copy of all the fields

Comment: That's it. It's a reference copy but not an object clone. However, `LinearLayout` doesn't implement `clone()` method. I guess I will have to think for a workaround.

Comment: One option would be to implement your own extension of `LinearLayout` and override the .clone() method